# Options for uploading entire folder contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to figure out the best way to upload the entire contents of a folder in an HTML5 / .NET MVC-4 project.  It looks like only Google Chrome supports the HTML5 drag and drop file upload functionality.  Is there another plugin that I can use to allow users to upload the entire contents of a folder?